# Prepared statements result in an error

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am very new to prepared statements.

This is my code:

```
<?php
$getImages=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM header_image_arabic");
$getImages->bind_param('s', '$images');
$getImages->execute();
$getImages->bind_result($returned_images);
while($img=$returned_images->fetch_object()){
?>
```

This is the error:

> Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference in C:\wamp\www\arabia\admin\includes\pan\imageHeader.php on line 22`

What does this error mean?

Comment: I try this too 'Your Common Sense' but really I can't understand this if there is any site you can suggest please write it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are number of things wrong here.

`'$images'` is a string containing 7 characters.  You want to pass the variable to `bind_param`, not a string.

```
$getImages->bind_param('s', $images);
```

Also, what *exactly* are you trying to bind to here?  There are no placeholders (question marks) in your query.  You can just use `$db->query()` here.  You only need to "prepare" a query when you are filling in data.

```
$getImages = $db->query('SELECT * FROM header_image_arabic');
if($getImages === FALSE){
    die($db->error);
}

while($img = $getImages->fetch_object()){
}
```

Another thing is the line: `$getImages->bind_result($returned_images);`.  `bind_result` is used to bind to the fields in the query.  You can't use that here, since you are doing `SELECT *`.  (Also, `fetch_object` and `bind_result` *cannot* be used together.  You need to use `get_result` (which only works with the mysqlnd driver) to be able to use `fetch_object`.)

So, if you wanted to use "prepared statements", it would look something like this:

```
$getImages = $db->prepare("SELECT image_id FROM header_image_arabic WHERE name = ?");

$getImages->bind_param('s', $images);
$getImages->execute();
$getImages->bind_result($returned_images);

while($getImages->fetch()){
    // This will get updated each iteration
    echo $returned_images;
}
```

Or like this (requires mysqlnd driver):

```
$getImages = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM header_image_arabic WHERE name = ?");

$getImages->bind_param('s', $images);
$getImages->execute();
$result = $getImages->get_result();

while($img = $result->fetch_object()){
    echo $img->image_id;
}
```

Comment: thanks for you reply I was watching a tutorial on this and I am wrong about putting $images as string ... but still need to understand 'Prepared statements' better way anyway thanks for your help

Comment: Glad I could be of help!  Prepared statements are nice once you know how to use them :-)

Comment: Thanks again @Rocket Hazmat now I understand what is the use of 'prepared statements' it's the first time I know about it.

by the way this was my original code
`<?php
    $getImages="SELECT * FROM header_image_arabic";
 $QgetImages=$db->query($getImages)or die($db->error);
 while($img=$QgetImages->fetch_object()){
 ?>`

Comment: @user3353181: That code is just fine.  Prepared statements are only needed when you are going to be adding in data from variables into the query.